# Why do I get Kubernetes error request: Forbidden from the IntelliJ Kubernetes plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a `~/.kube/config` that is working in the command line. I can run any `kubectl` command with no problem. The config points to an AWS EKS cluster and it follows the [aws guide to create kubeconfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/create-kubeconfig.html).

I can see that the Kubernetes plugin is able to parse the `~/.kube/config` because the cluster name shows up in the `Kubernetes service` view. 
[image: Kubernetes error]

But any attempt to get any information from this view will result on a `Kubernetes Request Error: Forbidden`.

Any idea on what is the cause or how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/.kube/config` for a AWS EKS cluster usually includes a section like this:

```
- name: arn:aws:eks:eu-west-1:xxxxx:cluster/yyyyyy
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1
      args:
      - --region
      - eu-west-1
      - eks
      - get-token
      - --cluster-name
      - yyyyyy
      command: aws
      env:
      - name: AWS_PROFILE
        value: eks
```

This works  in the cli because you probably have `aws` executable in your shell `PATH`, but when IntelliJ IDEA tries to find `aws` it will fail. An easy fix is to modify `~/.kube/config` so that it points to the **absolute path to aws** like so:

```
      command: /usr/local/bin/aws
```

In order to troubleshoot problems with the Kubernetes plugin you can `Help > Debug Log Settings...` and add

```
#com.intellij.kubernetes
```

Restart the IDE then `Help > Show Log in Finder` will get you to the log.